# Как сбросить выделение элемента TreeViewItem после удаления?

Tags: c#, wpf

После удаления выделенного TreeViewItem происходит автоматические выделение другого.

Каким образом определяется какой элемент будет выдлен автоматически?

Как сбросить выделение элемента TreeViewItem после удаления?

Comment: `SelectedItem = null;`

Answer (score 0):

У TreeView свойство SelectedItem доступно только для чтения. Поэтому надо либо добавлять в класс описывающий элемент дерева свойства IsSelected и IsExpanded, либо сделать универсальную обертку для произвольных элементов:

```
public class ItemWrapper<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T _data = default(T);

    public T Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_data))
            {
                _data = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isSelected = false;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isSelected)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isExpanded = false;

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get
        {
            return _isExpanded;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isExpanded)
            {
                _isExpanded = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ItemWrapper<T>> _children = null;

    public ObservableCollection<ItemWrapper<T>> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _children;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _children)
            {
                _children = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string p_propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p_propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Указываете нужный тип, в свойство Data помещаете ваш объект, в Children обернутых в аналогичный класс деток. Ну а дальше, добавляете в XAML вот такой ресурс:

```
<Окно или UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>
</Окно или UserControl.Resources>
```

Не забываем поменять Binding и у элементов дерева, на что-то такого:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Теперь вы можете меняя из кода свойства IsSelected и IsExpanded менять выбранный элемент и сворачивать/разворачивать элементы дерева.

Comment: Хм, не знал, что `TreeView` не наследует `Selector`